# LaTeX figure labeling using overpic: rescaling problems

Tags: graphics, scaling, overpic

I am using the [`overpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic) package to lay over different pictures in LaTeX. I am also labeling the axes of the figure using `\put`. The problem is say I have labeled the figure correctly. Now, sometime later I change the scaling of the figure. On change the scale the labels are getting messed up. Is there any way that the labels are also adjusted according to the scaling of the figure? Here is a part of my `.tex` file:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\hspace*{7.3cm}
\hspace*{0.5cm}\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{abstract.pdf}
    \put(103,3){\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{abpink.pdf}}
    \put(100,27){\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{abloop.pdf}}
    \put(93,48){\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{abgreen.pdf}}
    \put(72,57){\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{abangti.pdf}}
    \put(55,81){\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{abblue.pdf}}
    \put(-105,5){\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{abphase.pdf}}
    %\linethickness{1pt}
    \put(-9,69){\color{black}\vector(0,1){12}}
    \put(-10,82){$\hat{z}$}
    \put(-9,68){\color{black}\vector(0,-1){12}}
    \put(-11,51){$\hat{v}$}
    \put(-63,-1){$\theta$}
    \put(-115,44){$\partial_s\theta$}
    \put(-1.5,92){$q$}
    \put(88,-0.5){$|\bv|$}
    \put(-1,-0.5){$T$}
    \end{overpic}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: use `\scalebox` around the `overpic` environment to scale text and image together

Comment: why have you tagged this as tikz?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree; I've just reomved the `tikz` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Please always post usable documents including all macros defined, not just fragments.

You can scale the image and text together:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{overpic,color}\def\bv{b_v}

\begin{document}


\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \put(-9,69){\color{black}\vector(0,1){12}}
    \put(-10,82){$\hat{z}$}
    \put(-9,68){\color{black}\vector(0,-1){12}}
    \put(-11,51){$\hat{v}$}
    \put(-63,-1){$\theta$}
    \put(-115,44){$\partial_s\theta$}
    \put(-1.5,92){$q$}
    \put(88,-0.5){$|\bv|$}
    \put(-1,-0.5){$T$}
\end{overpic}

\vfill

\hrule

\vfill

\scalebox{.2}{%
\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \put(-9,69){\color{black}\vector(0,1){12}}
    \put(-10,82){$\hat{z}$}
    \put(-9,68){\color{black}\vector(0,-1){12}}
    \put(-11,51){$\hat{v}$}
    \put(-63,-1){$\theta$}
    \put(-115,44){$\partial_s\theta$}
    \put(-1.5,92){$q$}
    \put(88,-0.5){$|\bv|$}
    \put(-1,-0.5){$T$}
\end{overpic}}

\vfill

\hrule

\vfill

\scalebox{2}{%
\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \put(-9,69){\color{black}\vector(0,1){12}}
    \put(-10,82){$\hat{z}$}
    \put(-9,68){\color{black}\vector(0,-1){12}}
    \put(-11,51){$\hat{v}$}
    \put(-63,-1){$\theta$}
    \put(-115,44){$\partial_s\theta$}
    \put(-1.5,92){$q$}
    \put(88,-0.5){$|\bv|$}
    \put(-1,-0.5){$T$}
\end{overpic}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I do not want to scale the text. I want the text to be of the same fontsize. I only want the relative positioning of the text after I scale the figure. Is that possible?

Comment: @Brato isn't that automatic as overpic sets the picture mode coordinates based on the image size?

Comment: Nope. My \put commands for the labels are getting inside the figure on rescaling.